# React native, RCT_EXPORT_METHOD in view

Tags: ios, react-native

i have my own native component  and it works great. I would like to add a method to expose some value and i am not sure how this works, can i use RCT_EXPORT_METHOD on a view and if so how do i access it?

```
@implementation MyEditorManager {
}

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(initialValue, NSString)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(staticText, NSString)


RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

// i would like to call this !!!
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(hello:(NSString *)name) {

}


- (UIView *)view
{
    _field = [[RichTextEditor alloc] init]; 
    _field.delegate = self;
    return _field;
}
```

I would like to call this method hello. But i am not sure how to. My integration with react native looks like this.

```
var { requireNativeComponent } = require('react-native');
var React = require('react-native');

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Comp {...this.props} />
    );
  }
};

var Comp = requireNativeComponent('MyEditor', MyEditor,
  { nativeOnly: { onChange: true } } );

module.exports = MyEditor;
```

Ideally i would like to do something like that, but it does not work

```
// in render
<Editor ref='editor' />
// ...
// later call this.refs.hello('test')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call it like this:

```
var Comp = requireNativeComponent('MyEditor', MyEditor, { nativeOnly: { onChange: true } } )
Comp.hello('test')
```